# Can I `yarn create` from a repository hosted on GitHub instead of published NPM package?

Tags: yarnpkg

Can I use `yarn create` with a repository hosted on GitHub rather than a published NPM package?

This is possible for other commands, e.g. to install a dependency from a GitHub repository I can do `yarn add <git remote url>` or `yarn add <git remote url>#<branch/commit/tag>` to target something different than default branch.

I tried `yarn create <git remote url>` but facing an error:

```
$ yarn create <git remote url>
yarn create v1.22.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "create-https:: Invalid URI \"create-https:/\"".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/home/xxx/.config/yarn/global/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create for documentation about this command.
```

I'm using yarn v1.22.1.

Answer (score 0):

[As documented](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create/) `yarn create <starter-kit-package>` is just a shortcut for

```
yarn global add create-<starter-kit-package>
create-<starter-kit-package>
```

While it seems like `yarn create` does not support git repositories, the underlying commands do. So instead of `yarn create <git remote url>` or something similar I can do

```sh
yarn global add <git remote url>
<repository-name>
```

Lets take `react-app` starter kit as an example. Using the latest publish packaged I would do `yarn create react-app`, which is the same as

```sh
yarn global add create-react-app
create-react-app my-app
```

To use a feature branch I can do:

```
yarn global add https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#feature-branch
create-react-app my-app
```